# Passing function as argument to a Function, and using it on Generic object

Tags: java, function, generics

I would like to do something like below.

```
private <T> void sliceGenericData (List<T> peData, **FunctionType** getterFunctionX) {
    // ... Some Code ...


    <T>.getterFunction()


    // ... Some Code ...

}
```

A and B class will be my generic type as <T>. Example for a getter function for class A and B.

```
public class A{
  long x = 5;
  public long getterFunction1(){
     return x;
  }
}

public class B{
  long x = 1;
  public long getterFunction2(){
     return x;
  }
}
```

I want to pass a getterFunction as argument to my `sliceGenericData()` and I  would like to use it on type <T> (Class A or B). Since those classes have different name of getter functions as `getterFunction2, getterFunction1`. How can I do it?

Comment: *"with out any argument"* - you mean the function doesn't take arguments? And could you display what this pseudo code statement should mean `<T>.getterFunction()` ?

Comment: In other words, how your `Long`-producing parameterless function is related to `T`?

Comment: I edited the question @AlexanderIvanchenko . T type can have different getter function names.

Comment: Do you want to use a generic `T` for two classes completely independent classes and call a kind of Long supplier function of T?

Comment: @swinkler Yes, completely independent classes. And call a long supplier function of T.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a function taking the type as param and producing a Long like this:

```
private <T> void sliceGenericData (List<T> peData, Function<T, Long> fn) 
{ 
  ... 
  // apply your Object
  Long res = fn.apply(myObj);
  ...
}
```

Invoke the method by providing the appropriate method for the type:

```
sliceGenericData(myList, A::getterFunction1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think this is it. Let me test it and be sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your intention, you want to turn a `List<T>` into a `List<Long>`. I so your function should not be parameterless, instead it should consume an argument of type `T` to produce a `long` value.

But to make a function be capable to dial with these classes they need to conform to the same contract, and we already have such contract in the JDK - [`LongSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/LongSupplier.html).

And there's one more thing - if you make your classes implement `LongSupplier` interface, the function would not be needed.

**Note** that implementing the contract of `LongSupplier` would not affect your existing code anyhow. Method `getAsLong()` can delegate to methods like `getterFunction1()`.

```
public class A implements LongSupplier {
    
    public long getterFunction1() {
        // proper logic here
    }
    
    public long getAsLong() {
        return getterFunction1();
    }
}

public class B implements LongSupplier {

    public long getterFunction2() {
        // proper logic here
    }
    
    public long getAsLong() {
        return getterFunction2();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- If `A` and `B` differ only by the value of an attribute - you **don't** need two classes.
- Only if you have a more complicated logic of generating the resulting value (*instead of simply retrieving what is stored in a field*), it would be justifiable to have separate classes implementing that logic.

And your method might look like this:

```
private void sliceGenericData(List<LongSupplier> peData) {
    // ... Some Code ...

    List<Long> longs = peData.stream()
        .map(LongSupplier::getAsLong)
        .toList(); // or collect(Collectors.toList())
    
    // ... Some Code ...
    
}
```

Comment: I understand your inheritance logic.  Those two classes already implemented separate classes, The only common thing they have is they have a date value, stored as long. That is not what I would like to change. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @MericOzcan Not sure what is the language you're primarily working with, but in Java `class`es are being extended (not implemented, they already have implemented behavior). And a class in Java can extend only one class. But interfaces are contracts, they declare behavior that needs to be implemented. A class can `implement` **as many** interfaces as you need. There are **no** obstacles for your classes to implement `LongSupplier`, the method of the contact can simply delegate to your methods like `getterFunction1()`. This change would not affect your existing code anyhow.

Comment: I was C++ developer once :D I see. let me think about it more.